# PHP library or helper method to set values of nested associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working in PHP with what are essentially JSON objects (Highchart configs to be specific). So I might have something like the following:

```
$chart = [           
    'plotOptions' => [
        'column' => [
            'dataLabels' => [
                'enabled' => true
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'legend' => [
        'enabled' => false
    ],
    'yAxis' => [
        'title' => [
            'text' => null
        ]
    ]
];
```

I'm writing some code to build these config objects in the PHP and it's a pain to set nested properties because I have to check if the parent exists. For example, if I wanted to add a title to the xAxis to the config above, I'd have to do this:

```
if(!array_key_exists('xAxis', $chart)){
  $chart['xAxis'] = [];
}
$chart['xAxis']['title'] = 'x title';
```

This is especially annoying when I have a really deep property to set because I have to do a "array_key_exists" for each level.

I'm wondering if anyone has any idea on how to make this simpler and cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you already know the structure, you could just set the array directly instead of initiating an empty one. Like this: ```$chart['xAxis'] = ['title' => ['text' => 'x title']];```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function to create associative keys automatically.

```php
function setKey($key, $value, &$array) {
    $path = explode('.', $key);
    $arrayContext =& $array;
    foreach( $path as $segment ) {
        if( !isset($arrayContext[$segment]) ) {
            $arrayContext[$segment] = [];
        }
        $arrayContext =& $arrayContext[$segment];
    }
    $arrayContext = $value;
}
```

Then use dot notation to set the key value within the array (e.g. "xAxis.title" is the same as $chart['xAxis']['title']):

```php
setKey('xAxis.title', 'x title', $chart);
```

This can be read as "set the value of the key xAxis -> title to 'x title' in the $chart array variable."